# Is there an alternative to string.Replace that is case-insensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-2.0, replace

I need to search a string and replace all occurrences of `%FirstName%` and `%PolicyAmount%` with a value pulled from a database. The problem is the capitalization of FirstName varies. That prevents me from using the `String.Replace()` method. I've seen web pages on the subject that suggest

```
Regex.Replace(strInput, strToken, strReplaceWith, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However for some reason when I try and replace `%PolicyAmount%` with `$0`, the replacement never takes place. I assume that it has something to do with the dollar sign being a reserved character in regex.

Is there another method I can use that doesn't involve sanitizing the input to deal with regex special characters?

Comment: If "$0" is the variable going in that doesn't impact the regex at all.

Comment: As [Markus points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63315139/1028230), it appears "modern" versions of .NET now have this baked in with good ole `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as a third parameter.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx)
$0 - "Substitutes the last substring matched by group number number (decimal)."

In .NET Regular expressions group 0 is always the entire match. For a literal $ you need to

```
string value = Regex.Replace("%PolicyAmount%", "%PolicyAmount%", @"$$0", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: in this particular case this is fine, but in cases where the strings are input from outside, one cannot be sure that they do not contain characters which mean something special in regular expressions

Comment: You should escape special characters like this: string value = Regex.Replace("%PolicyAmount%", Regex.Escape("%PolicyAmount%"), Regex.Escape("$0"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Actually regex-escaping the second string will have no effect apart getting an extra \ before the replacement. To ignore special characters in the replacement string, you'd better write a matchevaluator that returns the string itself.

Comment: Please watch out when using Regex.Escape in Regex.Replace. You'll have to escape all of the three strings passed and call Regex.Unescape on the result!

Comment: According to msdn: "Character escapes are recognized in regular expression patterns but not in replacement patterns." ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e.aspx )

Comment: @HolgerAdam hm, i cannnot get your comment. "Regex.Replace("a[b]b", Regex.Escape("]B"), Regex.Escape("]C"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)" returns a[b]C, as expected. Can you explain why you think one needs to escape the input and unescape after?

Comment: It's best to use:  string value = Regex.Replace("%PolicyAmount%", Regex.Escape("%PolicyAmount%"), "$0".Replace("$", "$$"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);  as replacement recognizes only dolar signs.

Answer (score 304):

Seems like `string.Replace` *should* have an overload that takes a `StringComparison` argument. Since it doesn't, you could try something like this:

```
public static string ReplaceString(string str, string oldValue, string newValue, StringComparison comparison)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int previousIndex = 0;
    int index = str.IndexOf(oldValue, comparison);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        sb.Append(str.Substring(previousIndex, index - previousIndex));
        sb.Append(newValue);
        index += oldValue.Length;

        previousIndex = index;
        index = str.IndexOf(oldValue, index, comparison);
    }
    sb.Append(str.Substring(previousIndex));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Extension methods only work in 3+ right? +1 All the same, since the OP wasn't specific, but you may want to mention it

Comment: Also, this will be faster than the regex.

Comment: Nice. I would change `ReplaceString` to `Replace`.

Comment: Agree with the comments above. This can be made into an extension method with the same method name. Just pop it in a static class with the method signature: 

public static string Replace(this String str, string oldValue, string newValue, StringComparison comparison)

Comment: Speed is not everything. Use the regex instead of doing it yourself, introducing additional complexity and potentially also bugs. Additionally the regex solution is much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @Helge, in general, that may be fine, but I have to take arbitrary strings from the user and can not risk the input being meaningful to regex. Of course, I guess I could write a loop and put a backslash in front of each and every character... At that point, I might as well do the above (IMHO).

Comment: @Jim - I agree on using this solution instead, but just in case you ever need it, you can use [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) to escape regex-important characters for you.

Comment: @JamesManning - Hmm, interesting--didn't know about Escape(). Thanks.

Comment: While unit testing this I ran into the case where it would never return when `oldValue == newValue == ""`.

Comment: For the case of oldValue = "", String.Replace doesn't allow it. I added exception checks to match String.Replace exceptions: `if (oldValue == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("oldValue"); } if (oldValue == "") { throw new ArgumentException("String cannot be of zero length.", "oldValue"); }`

Comment: Great work here. I turned it into an extension method, but more importantly, I added a fast-out at the top in the case where str doesn't contain oldValue. Just move the `int index = str.IndexOf(oldValue, comparison);` to the first line of the method and return `str` if `index == -1`

Comment: This is buggy; `ReplaceString("œ", "oe", "", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)` throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Just learn Regex, keep the code clean. This is a trivial example but still looks complicated. People obsessing about speed and then writing crummy code like this is unfortunate.

Comment: @Jaycee, having to escape the replacement string by default does not look like clean code to me.  Also I'm sure the actual Regex implementation itself looks way more complicated and probably had numerous bugs in its initial versions.  I do hope a final bug free version is posted.

Comment: @crokusek I use regex extensively and there are no bugs I have noticed. You are much more likely to introduce a bug with custom code like this.

Comment: Using `StringBuilder` in this way will likely not improve performance the way you intend; it will be initialised with a 16 character buffer and your loop will potentially cause a number of memory allocations and copies. You should initialise your `StringBuilder` to a suitable capacity before you begin appending strings to it.

Comment: @MichaelLiu What do you think of `if(oldValue.Length > str.Length) return str;` ... Any weird stuff this could cause. I've wrote a few tests, all are using `OrdinalIgnoreCase` and that workaround didn't break any. I might be missing some cases, of course, so what do you think?

Comment: @MichaelLiu Here are the tests for this Replace https://gist.github.com/Galilyou/00dcd0dab2d2a050c30c

Comment: @Galilyou: The problem I pointed out isn't with the length check; the problem is with IndexOf and StringComparison.InvariantCulture.

Comment: note: `ReplaceString("","","",StringComparison.CurrentCulture)` will lead to an infinite loop!

Comment: @WaldenLeverich So with your fast-out you avoid instantiating the StringBuilder but introduce an `if` statement? Seems a micro-optimisation (if that) to me.

Comment: @Caltor It's not just the constructor, but the string copy after the while() and then the .ToString back to a string as well. These things add up. But more importantly that that, there's the developer benefit of quickly seeing what happens if there's no match. BTW, check MS's code for similar checks, the do fast-exit checks as well.

Answer (score 46):

Kind of a confusing group of answers, in part because the title of the question is actually *much* larger than the specific question being asked. After reading through, I'm not sure any answer is a few edits away from assimilating all the good stuff here, so I figured I'd try to sum.

Here's an extension method that I think avoids the pitfalls mentioned here and provides the most broadly applicable solution.

```
public static string ReplaceCaseInsensitiveFind(this string str, string findMe,
    string newValue)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str,
        Regex.Escape(findMe),
        Regex.Replace(newValue, "\\$[0-9]+", @"$$$0"),
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

So...

- This is [an extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive#comment5549925_244933) @MarkRobinson
- This [doesn't try to skip Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive#comment5771414_244933) @Helge (you really have to do byte-by-byte if you want to string sniff like this outside of Regex)
- Passes @MichaelLiu 's [excellent test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive#comment31063745_244933), `"œ".ReplaceCaseInsensitiveFind("oe", "")`, though he may have had a slightly different behavior in mind.

Unfortunately, [@HA 's comment that you have to `Escape` all three isn't correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive/244933#comment19010354_244585). The initial value and `newValue` doesn't need to be.

**Note:** You do, however, have to escape `$`s in the new value that you're inserting **if they're part of what would appear to be a "captured value" marker**. Thus the three dollar signs in the Regex.Replace inside the Regex.Replace [sic]. Without that, something like this breaks...

`"This is HIS fork, hIs spoon, hissssssss knife.".ReplaceCaseInsensitiveFind("his", @"he$0r")`

Here's the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: parsing "The\hisr\ is\ he\HISr\ fork,\ he\hIsr\ spoon,\ he\hisrsssssss\ knife\." - Unrecognized escape sequence \h.
```

Tell you what, I know folks that are comfortable with Regex feel like their use avoids errors, but I'm often still partial to byte sniffing strings (but only after having read [Spolsky on encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)) to be absolutely sure you're getting what you intended for important use cases. Reminds me of Crockford on "[insecure regular expressions](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/jslint-errors-and-options-described.html#fbid=49_PApIFUSX)" a little. Too often we write regexps that allow what we want (if we're lucky), but unintentionally allow more in (eg, Is `$10` really a valid "capture value" string in my newValue regexp, above?) because we weren't thoughtful enough. Both methods have value, and both encourage different types of unintentional errors. It's often easy to underestimate complexity.

That weird `$` escaping (and that `Regex.Escape` didn't escape captured value patterns like `$0` as I would have expected in replacement values) drove me mad for a while. Programming Is Hard (c) 1842

Answer (score 34):

Seems the easiest method is simply to use the Replace method that ships with .Net and has been around since .Net 1.0:

```
string res = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Replace(res, 
                                   "%PolicyAmount%", 
                                   "$0", 
                                   Compare: Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text);
```

In order to use this method, you have to add a Reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assemblly.  This assembly is a standard part of the .Net runtime, it is not an extra download or marked as obsolete.

Comment: It works. You need to add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.

Comment: Strange that this method had some problems when I used it (characters at the beginning of line went missing).  The  most popular answer here from `C. Dragon 76` worked as expected.

Comment: The problem with this is it returns a NEW string even if a replacement isn't made, where the string.replace( ) returns a pointer to the same string.  Can get inefficient if you're doing something like a form letter merge.

Comment: Brain2000, you are wrong. All strings in .NET are immutable.

Comment: Der_Meister, whilst what you say is correct, that doesn't make what Brain2000 said wrong.

Comment: Is the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly being deprecated? Various portions appear to be in deprecation lists such that relying on it in general could be a maintenance risk. Caveat Emptor.

Answer (score 33):

Here's an extension method. Not sure where I found it.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Replace(this string originalString, string oldValue, string newValue, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            startIndex = originalString.IndexOf(oldValue, startIndex, comparisonType);
            if (startIndex == -1)
                break;

            originalString = originalString.Substring(0, startIndex) + newValue + originalString.Substring(startIndex + oldValue.Length);

            startIndex += newValue.Length;
        }

        return originalString;
    }

}
```

Comment: You may need to handle empty/null string cases.

Comment: Mutiple errors in this solution: 1. Check originalString, oldValue and newValue for null. 2. Do not give orginalString back (does not work, simple types are not passed by reference), but assign the value of orginalValue first to a new string and modify it and give it back.

Answer (score 11):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A case insenstive replace function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalString">The string to examine.(HayStack)</param>
    /// <param name="oldValue">The value to replace.(Needle)</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">The new value to be inserted</param>
    /// <returns>A string</returns>
    public static string CaseInsenstiveReplace(string originalString, string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        Regex regEx = new Regex(oldValue,
           RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        return regEx.Replace(originalString, newValue);
    }
```

Comment: Which is better way ? what's about http://stackoverflow.com/a/244933/206730 ? better performance?

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by cfeduke's answer, I made this function which uses IndexOf to find the old value in the string and then replaces it with the new value. I used this in an SSIS script processing millions of rows, and the regex-method was way slower than this.

```
public static string ReplaceCaseInsensitive(this string str, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    int prevPos = 0;
    string retval = str;
    // find the first occurence of oldValue
    int pos = retval.IndexOf(oldValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    while (pos > -1)
    {
        // remove oldValue from the string
        retval = retval.Remove(pos, oldValue.Length);

        // insert newValue in it's place
        retval = retval.Insert(pos, newValue);

        // check if oldValue is found further down
        prevPos = pos + newValue.Length;
        pos = retval.IndexOf(oldValue, prevPos, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: +1 for not using regex when its not necessary. Sure, you use a few more lines of code, but its much more efficient than regex-based replace unless you need the $ functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on [C. Dragon 76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive#answer-244933)'s popular answer by making his code into an extension that overloads the default `Replace` method.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Replace(this string str, string oldValue, string newValue, StringComparison comparison)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int previousIndex = 0;
        int index = str.IndexOf(oldValue, comparison);
        while (index != -1)
        {
            sb.Append(str.Substring(previousIndex, index - previousIndex));
            sb.Append(newValue);
            index += oldValue.Length;

            previousIndex = index;
            index = str.IndexOf(oldValue, index, comparison);
        }
        sb.Append(str.Substring(previousIndex));
        return sb.ToString();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since .NET Core 2.0 or .NET Standard 2.1 respectively, this is baked into the .NET runtime [1]:

```
"hello world".Replace("World", "csharp", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); // "hello csharp"
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_StringComparison_

Answer (score 3):

Based on Jeff Reddy's answer, with some optimisations and validations:

```
public static string Replace(string str, string oldValue, string newValue, StringComparison comparison)
{
    if (oldValue == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("oldValue");
    if (oldValue.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("String cannot be of zero length.", "oldValue");

    StringBuilder sb = null;

    int startIndex = 0;
    int foundIndex = str.IndexOf(oldValue, comparison);
    while (foundIndex != -1)
    {
        if (sb == null)
            sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length + (newValue != null ? Math.Max(0, 5 * (newValue.Length - oldValue.Length)) : 0));
        sb.Append(str, startIndex, foundIndex - startIndex);
        sb.Append(newValue);

        startIndex = foundIndex + oldValue.Length;
        foundIndex = str.IndexOf(oldValue, startIndex, comparison);
    }

    if (startIndex == 0)
        return str;
    sb.Append(str, startIndex, str.Length - startIndex);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a version similar to C. Dragon's, but for if you only need a single replacement:

```
int n = myText.IndexOf(oldValue, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
if (n >= 0)
{
    myText = myText.Substring(0, n)
        + newValue
        + myText.Substring(n + oldValue.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option for executing Regex replacements, since not many people seem to notice the matches contain the location within the string:

```
    public static string ReplaceCaseInsensative( this string s, string oldValue, string newValue ) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        int offset = oldValue.Length - newValue.Length;
        int matchNo = 0;
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, Regex.Escape(oldValue), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            sb.Remove(match.Index - (offset * matchNo), match.Length).Insert(match.Index - (offset * matchNo), newValue);
            matchNo++;
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain why you're multiplying by MatchNo?

Comment: If there is a difference in length between the oldValue and newValue, the string will get longer or shorter as you replace values. match.Index refers to the original location within the string, we need to adjust for that positions movement due to our replacement.  Another approach would be to execute the Remove/Insert from right to left.

Comment: I get that. That's what the "offset" variable is for. What I don't understand is why you are multiplying by matchNo. My intuition tells me that the location of a match within a string would have no relation to the actual count of previous occurrences.

Comment: Never mind, I get it now. The offset needs to be scaled based on the # of occurrences. If you are losing 2 characters each time you need to do a replace, you need to account for that when computing the parameters to the remove method

Answer (score 1):

Let me make my case and then you can tear me to shreds if you like.

Regex is not the answer for this problem - too slow and memory hungry, relatively speaking.

StringBuilder is much better than string mangling.

Since this will be an extension method to supplement `string.Replace`, I believe it important to match how that works - therefore throwing exceptions for the same argument issues is important as is returning the original string if a replacement was not made.

I believe that having a StringComparison parameter is not a good idea.
I did try it but the test case originally mentioned by michael-liu showed a problem:-

```
[TestCase("œ", "oe", "", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, Result = "")]
```

Whilst IndexOf will match, there is a mismatch between the length of the match in the source string (1) and oldValue.Length (2). This manifested itself by causing IndexOutOfRange in some other solutions when oldValue.Length was added to the current match position and I could not find a way around this.
Regex fails to match the case anyway, so I took the pragmatic solution of only using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` for my solution.

My code is similar to other answers but my twist is that I look for a match before going to the trouble of creating a `StringBuilder`. If none is found then a potentially large allocation is avoided. The code then becomes a `do{...}while` rather than a `while{...}`

I have done some extensive testing against other Answers and this came out fractionally faster and used slightly less memory.

```
    public static string ReplaceCaseInsensitive(this string str, string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        if (str == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
        if (oldValue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(oldValue));
        if (oldValue.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("String cannot be of zero length.", nameof(oldValue));

        var position = str.IndexOf(oldValue, 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (position == -1) return str;

        var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);

        var lastPosition = 0;

        do
        {
            sb.Append(str, lastPosition, position - lastPosition);

            sb.Append(newValue);

        } while ((position = str.IndexOf(oldValue, lastPosition = position + oldValue.Length, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1);

        sb.Append(str, lastPosition, str.Length - lastPosition);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I would guess that a change of the `StringBuffer` initialization to `var sb = new StringBuilder(newValue.Length > oldValue.Length ? (int)(text.Length * 1.2) : text.Length);` would even improve the speed slightly in most cases where the new substring is longer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(strInput, strToken.Replace("$", "[$]"), strReplaceWith, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The $ is not in the token. It's in the strReplace With string.

Comment: And you can't adapt it for that?

Comment: This site is supposed to be a repository for correct answers. Not answers that are almost correct.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression method should work.  However what you can also do is lower case the string from the database, lower case the %variables% you have, and then locate the positions and lengths in the lower cased string from the database.  Remember, positions in a string don't change just because its lower cased.

Then using a loop that goes in reverse (its easier, if you do not you will have to keep a running count of where later points move to) remove from your non-lower cased string from the database the %variables% by their position and length and insert the replacement values.

Comment: By reverse, I mean process the found locations in reverse from furthest to shortest, not traverse the string from the database in reverse.

Comment: You could, or you could just use the Regex :)

Answer (score 0):

(Since everyone is taking a shot at this). Here's my version (with null checks, and correct input and replacement escaping) ** Inspired from around the internet and other versions:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class MyExtensions {
    public static string ReplaceIgnoreCase(this string search, string find, string replace) {
        return Regex.Replace(search ?? "", Regex.Escape(find ?? ""), (replace ?? "").Replace("$", "$$"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);          
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = "This is a test".ReplaceIgnoreCase("IS", "was");
```