# Case insensitive replace without using regular expression in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there a way to do case insensitive replace on a string without using regular expression in C#?

something like this

```
string x = "Hello";

x = x.Replace("hello", "hello world");
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you mean?

Comment: A good solution is found in this thread by @c-dragon-76 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like

```
string str = "Hello";
string replace = "hello";
string replaceWith = "hello world";
int i = str.IndexOf(replace, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
int len = replace.Length;
str = str.Replace(str.Substring(i, len), replaceWith);
```

Have a look at [String.IndexOf Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx)

Comment: I doubt that `Replace` will be able to replace the string. Its a different matter that you got index by ignoring the case. Is it a tested example?

Comment: Yes, I have tested this. Just remember that I am retrieving the start index based on the search string, but replacing based on the sub string from the original string, so it will match.

Comment: it doesn't work as we would expected in other situations... e.g. if `str = "Hello-Hello"` it will return `"hello world-hello world"` but it's `str="Hello-hello"` it will return `"hello world-hello"`... this partial solution need to be redesign.

Comment: That only replaces the first occurrence, not all. If you where to put it in a loop and make it an extension method, that would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

The following links may be of help.

[Is there an alternative to string.Replace that is case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/fastestcscaseinsstringrep.aspx

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/60355.aspx

There is also the [Strings.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.replace.aspx) function in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly.