# Out of curiosity - is there a better performing approach to do this string replace?

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have the below method where I need to check for some certain strings which could be in any case and then remove them. Just wondered if there was a better performing way?

```
private void MyMethod(string Filter)
{
   //need to remove <Filter> and </Filter> case in-sensitive
   var result = Filter.ToLower().Replace("<filter>","");
   result = Filter.ToLower().Replace("</filter>,"");

  ...........................
}
```

Comment: `Regex.Replace(Filter, "</?filter>", string.empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); ` If you are interested in the performance of various methods, there are plenty of discussions about it here on SO.

Comment: isnt it going to change the case of whats in between the tags. or it does not matter to you.

Comment: `ToUpper` is a better option than `ToLower`. String comparison and replacement has been optimized for the former. From the developer's perspective, there's no difference so it's a simple fix.

Comment: @Cody Gray - Do you have any link that verifies this? I would like to learn why that makes any difference.

Comment: @Øyvind: Not really. I remember reading it in the Framework Design Guidelines, and it's never mattered enough to me to take the time to verify it myself. It *does* work properly with foreign characters, though, when `ToLower` might produce unexpected results. I think that's what was meant by the recommendation.

Comment: @Øyvind: Actually, it turns out that it's `ToUpperInvariant`. Which makes sense; that's what you should be using anyway. And here you go with some links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c#12137 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx, specifically "Recommendations for String Use"

Comment: @Cody Gray - Thanks a lot. It seems that it's to prevent unexpected results, and not performance, and that gives a lot more sense (even if I would never have guessed on my own). You learn something new every day ;)

Comment: You can also stack .replace(). You can write the code as string.replace().replace()... Should save a few extra cycles there by not having to run the equation again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem with that approach is that it will turn the entire string into lower case, not just make a case insensetive replace.

You can use a regular expression to do a case insensetive match:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(
  Filter,
  "</?filter>",
  String.Empty,
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

Another alternative is to use the `IndexOf` method to locate the strings, as it can do a case insensetive search:

```
string result = Filter;
int index;
while ((index = IndexOf("<filter>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1) {
   result = result.Remove(index, 8);
}
while ((index = IndexOf("</filter>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1) {
   result = result.Remove(index, 9);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this answer: [Is there an alternative to string.Replace that is case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive/244933#244933)

You might want to do a comparison with a performance check. Profile this with a profiler. It is the only way to really know, what is faster.

But honestly: Does performance really matter? How often are you doing this? I can't really see you doing this so often, that performance will become an issue...

You could try `Regex.Replace`, with a case insensitive replace. This is not faster. But it is case insensitive.

Comment: Why do you think a regex is going to be faster? And if not, why do you recommend trying that instead?

Comment: I do not think he asserted that `Regex.Replace` is faster, quite the contrary.

Comment: No, I don't think Regex.Replace is faster. But it does do a case insensitive replace. I will update my answer.

Comment: I do think RegEx will be faster under certain conditions. Not sure if it's the case here, the OP will have to profile.

Answer (score 1):

`Replace` calls to unmanaged code which is implemented in C++ which I imagine will be hard to beat.

However, I can see you keep using `.ToLower()` which you can cut down to one call and keeping the string.

Comment: I think the ToLower() stuff could be a problem. Also, the output string is now lowercase.

Comment: Yes, I was just typing the words :)

Comment: @Henk I used reflector-> it calls to `ReplaceInternal` which is an `extern` interop method.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you are lower-casing your original string here, which might not be a good thing?

Comment: The comments in the code indicate that the intention is to perform a case-insensitive replacement. I assume that's why the string is being converted to lower case.

Comment: @Cody Gray - That is true, but the problem here is that the part of the string that is not replaced, it also converted to all lower-case. I think that is bjornars concern here. (even if this is more of a comment than an answer actually)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a few things, how long the Filter string is etc.
So you will have to measure.

But I would expect a (single!) RegEx to be faster here.

Comment: What if you have 50 strings to replace here for some reason. Won' tthe RegEx be incredible messy?

Comment: @Oyvind: It would be very fast, the more the better.

Comment: I wasn't referring to speed, but the readability of the code. Any way to make that look even remotely good? (I don't now RegEx, that's why I'm asking ;) )

Comment: @Oyvind: `@"\<filter\>|\</filter\>"` . Could even shorten that to `@"\</?filter\>"` but the `|` gives the general pattern: `text1|text2|text3`, and then escape the RegEx tokens

Answer (score 0):

If the provided code works for you, than this will be faster:

```
private void MyMethod(string Filter)
{
   //need to remove <Filter> and </Filter> case in-sensitive
   var result = Filter.ToLower().Replace("</filter>","");

  ...........................
}
```

as the first statement's result is ignored.

Comment: You're missing a closing double quote.  Also, this doesn't produce the same result.  It just removes one of the steps.  Essentially, your code isn't doing what the comment above it says.

Comment: True, but it IS doing the same thing as the provided code, but faster, as both replaces are done on `Filter.ToLower()`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time not upvoting this. I shouldn't and won't. But you made me smile :)

Comment: You are correct in that the original code actually does produce a result that is discarded. However that is most likely not what was intended with the code, as it doesn't make much sense.