# Regex.Replace with large strings and backslashes

Tags: c#, regex

I have written a utility which opens a text based file, loads is as a string and performs a find / replace function using `RegEx.Replace`.

It does this on many files, the user points it at a folder, enters a find string, a replace string and all the files in the folder which contain the string in the file get replaced.

This works great until I try it with a backslash where it falls down.

Quite simply:

```
newFileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, @findString, @replaceString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

fileContent = the contents of a text based file. it will contain carriage returns.

findString = user entered string to find

replaceString = user entered string to replace the found string with

I've tried adding some logic to counter act the backslash as below, but this fails with illegal at end of pattern.

```
 if (culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(findString, @"\") >= 0)
     {
      Regex.Replace(findString, @"\", @"\\");
     }
```

What do I need to do to successfully handle backslashes so they can be part of the find / replace logic?

Entire code block below.

```
//open reader
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(f,Encoding.Default)) 
                {
                    //read file
                    var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    Globals.AppendTextToLine(string.Format(" replacing string"));

                    //culture find replace
                    var culture = new CultureInfo("en-gb", false);
                    //ensure nothing has changed
                    if (culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(fileContent, findString, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {

                        //if find or replace string contains backslahes
                        if (culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(findString, @"\") >= 0)
                        {
                            Regex.Replace(findString, @"\", @"\\");
                        }

                        //perform replace in new string
                        if (MainWindow.Main.chkIgnoreCase.IsChecked != null && (bool) MainWindow.Main.chkIgnoreCase.IsChecked)                        
                            newFileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, @findString, @replaceString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        else
                            newFileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, @findString, @replaceString);

                        result[i].Result = true;
                        Globals.AppendTextToLine(string.Format(" success!"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Globals.AppendTextToLine(string.Format(" failure!!"));
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Some food for thought: What if I put a file in a folder with a size that exceeds the amount of memory you have? Currently your solution will fail. Perhaps you should do the replaces line-by-line instead of on the entire file at once.

Comment: Allowing the user to put in a regex string is usually a bad idea as they can easily shoot themselves in the foot. An exception might be a dev tool - on which the user should both know it's a regex beforehand AND be knowledgeable enough to escape their backslashes. A layman doing a regex is not something that will work and you should probably rethink your approach.

Comment: Appreachate the feedback, however it is a support tool for a technical help desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) when you pass the user-input into the `Replace` method.

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $, .,
>   #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters
>   literally rather than as metacharacters.

For example:

```
newFileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent,
                               Regex.Escape(findString),
                               replaceString,
                               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Out of interest - if you ARE escaping the special chars what does Regex.Replace 'offer' over String.Replace?

Comment: @tolanj: The main benefit that springs immediately to mind is that it allows you to perform case-insensitive searches by passing the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag.

Comment: thanks, I would have sworn there was a built in String.Replace that took a StringComparison at least,  but indeed there is not..
Seems a common fallacy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549426/is-there-a-case-insensitive-string-replace-in-net-without-using-regex

Comment: Indeed it is the ignoring of the case that forces me to use RegEx

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental issue is that your letting your user enter an arbitrary regexp and thus, well, its interpreted as a regexp...

either you goal is *just* to replace literal strings,  in which-case use String.Replace OR you *want* to allow a user to enter a regexp, in which case just accept that the user will need to \ escape their special characters.

Since \ is a regexp escape char (As well as c# one but you seem to be dealing with that with @) "\" is an illegal regexp because *what are you escaping*

If you *Really* want a rexexp to replace all \ with \\ then its:

```
Regex.Replace(findString, @"\\", @"\\\\"); --ie one \ after escape, two chars after escape.
```

But you've still got [].?* etc to worry about.

My strong advice is a checkbox, user can select if they are entering a regexp or string literal for replacement and then call String.Replace or Regex.Replace accordingly

Comment: A good answer because you cover both findhString as a regex and literal, but if its a literal only metachars need to be escaped (includes `\ ` itself) . +1