# How to replace a word in a string

Tags: c#, string, replace

It is very basic question but i am not sure why it is not working. I have code where 'And' can be written in any of the ways 'And', 'and', etc. and i want to replace it with ','

I tried this:

```
and.Replace("and".ToUpper(),",");
```

but this is not working, any other way to do this or make it work?

Comment: That is equivalent to `and.Replace("AND", ",")`. In any case, look at Regex.Replace and case-insensitivity mode.

Comment: As @pst mentioned, you can use regex too: `var regex = new Regex( "camel", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
var newSentence = regex.Replace( sentence, "horse" );
` code take from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025560/how-to-ignore-case-in-string-replace

Comment: You can also use the "(?i)and" option in the search pattern. This way you can use the static `Replace()` method since you don't need to use the `RegexOption.IgnoreCase` enum. I gave some code below.

Comment: You should consider that sentence can contain words like 'sand'. The Regex will replace them as well. That's not correct.

Comment: I've made an StringExtensions project that provides an overload of Replace taking a ComparisonType, see: http://stringextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66ba3d678467#src%2fStringExtensions%2fCommonStringExtensions.Replace.cs

Now, you can simply say: `mystring.Replace("and", ",", StringComparison.InvariantIgnoreCase);` which is way more performant than any regex solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out the Regex class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex re = new Regex("\band\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string and = "This is my input string with and string in between.";

re.Replace(and, ",");
```

Comment: Good use of `\b` (+1). I prefer to use the Regex static methods, but that's mostly just preference ..

Answer (score 2):

```
words = words.Replace("AND", ",")
             .Replace("and", ",");
```

Or use RegEx.

Comment: He haven't mentioned in fact, but I think that you must to consider `And`, `aNd` `ANd` inputs etc. So, converts the input string and search string to even case and do the replace, or use only regex.

Comment: @Jack Yea that was just an example.  I mean he could continue to chain the .Replace methods on or your RegEx as I mentioned.  Since its just a limited number of combinations .Replace isn't that bad.

Answer (score 2):

The `Replace` method returns a string where the replacement is visible. It does **not** modify the original string. You should try something along the lines of

```
and = and.Replace("and",",");
```

You can do this for all variations of "and" you may encounter, or as other answers have suggested, you could use a regex.

Comment: While true, this will not help with "Jack And Jill".

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should take care if some words contain `and`, say `"this is sand and sea"`. The word "sand" must not be influenced by the replacement.

```
string and = "this is sand and sea";

//here you should probably add those delimiters that may occur near your "and"
//this substitution is not universal and will omit smth like this " and, " 
string[] delimiters = new string[] { " " }; 

//it result in: "this is sand , sea"
and = string.Join(" ", 
                  and.Split(delimiters,  
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Select(s => s.Length == 3 && s.ToUpper().Equals("AND") 
                                     ? "," 
                                     : s));
```

I would also add smth like this:

```
and = and.Replace(" , ", ", ");
```

So, the output:

```
this is sand, sea
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way to use the static `Regex.Replace()` method:

```
and = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(and,"(?i)and",",");
```

The "(?i)" causes the following text search to be case-insensitive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.100).aspx