# Efficient code: Removes tags from string except the first one

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wrote a function that searches given tags in a string and removes all those tags and their content, except the first one:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fileAsString = "<div>myFirstDiv</div>" +
                        "<Div></dIV>" +
                        "<city>NY</city>" +
                        "<city></city>" +
                        "<div></div>" +
                        "<span></span>"

    ' Removes these tags and their content from fileAsString, except the 
    ' first appearance

    Dim forbiddenNodeslist As New List(Of String)
    forbiddenNodeslist.Add("div")
    forbiddenNodeslist.Add("city")

    ' Run all over the forbidden tags

    For Each node In forbiddenNodeslist

        Dim re = New Regex("<" + node + "[^>]*>(.*?)</" + node + ">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        Dim matches = re.Matches(fileAsString)

        Dim matchesCount = matches.Count - 1

        ' Count the characters that were replaced by empty string, in order 
        ' to update the start index of the other matches

        Dim removedCharacters = 0

        ' Run all over the matches, except the first one

        For index = 1 To matches.Count - 1
            Dim match = matches(index)

            ' set start index and length in order to replace it by empty string

            Dim startIndex = match.Index - removedCharacters
            Dim matchCharactersCount = match.Length

            ' Update the number of characters that will be removed

            removedCharacters = matchCharactersCount

            ' Remove it from the string

            fileAsString = fileAsString.Remove(startIndex, matchCharactersCount)

        Next


    Next
end sub
```

But it inefficient cause I search the matches (first loop of the string) and then loop again and again in order to replace it by empty string.

How can I make it more efficient?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing the removedCharacters and positions of removed tags? If not, this is just additional overhead. Loop through your list of offending tags to remove and use a single statement to remove/replace all occurrences. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025560/how-to-ignore-case-in-string-replace

Comment: Yes, I store it cause when I remove some string, the start index of the next match will need to be updated. For example: "<div></div><div></div><div></div>", first div appears at index 0, the second at 11, the third at 22.
when I remove the second div, the third div will be at index 11 instead of 22.

Comment: You could reverse the whole string and then just remove all but the LAST occurrence, then reverse again to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I answered this in C#. You can find the fiddle I used [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YKcjVD)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var fileAsString = "<div>myFirstDiv</div><Div></dIV><city>NY</city><city></city><div></div><span></span>";

    //Using pipe delimited, this will come in handy for our second regex
    var delimetedForbiddenList = "div|city";

    //Use this regex to get everything that isn't the first tag
    var allButFirstTagRegex = new Regex(@"^(<([a-z]+)>[^</]*</\2>)(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var matches = allButFirstTagRegex.Matches(fileAsString);


    //matches[0].Groups[1] = (<([a-z]+)>[^</]*</\2>) -- the complete first 
    //tag (open, close, and inner), we'll use this later

    //matches[0].Groups[2] = ([a-zA-Z]+) --the first opening tag
    //used to get a matching close tag

    //matches[0].Groups[3] = (.*) -- everything not in the first tag        

    var allButFirstTag = matches[0].Groups[3].ToString();

    //allButFirstTag ==  @"<Div></dIV><city>NY</city><city></city><div></div><span></span>"

    //the regex to remove our forbidden tags
    var removeForbiddenPattern = String.Format("(<({0})>[^</]*</\\2>)", delimetedForbiddenList);
    //removeForbiddenPattern == new Regex(@"(<(div|city)>[^</]*</\2>)");

    var resultsWithForbiddenRemoved = Regex.Replace(allButFirstTag, removeForbiddenPattern, String.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    //resultsWithForbiddenRemoved == @"<span></span>"

    var finalResults = matches[0].Groups[1].ToString() + resultsWithForbiddenRemoved;
    //finalResults = <div>myFirstDiv</div><span></span>

}
```