# How can I check if a string is part of another string then replace it

Tags: c#, string, linq

For example,string A = "your"
            string B ="YOU"

Result string A = "YOU YOUr".

I have no problem replacing the first word, but for the second word, i cant seem to get the "r" to append to the word.

---

var description =  "you your"
STRING[] keywords ={"YOU","a"}

return description.Split().Select(x => keywords.Contains(x) ? x.ToUpper() : x).ToString(" ");

so far, I can get "YOU your", but "YOU YOUr" is what I want.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.  Demonstrate that you have done your research before asking here.

Comment: actually ops.. my old attempt didnt work...

Comment: I am gonna repost this question -5 already in 5 minutes lol

Comment: I don't even completely understand what the question is here. something that involves using IndexOf and Replace probably fixes whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand you correctly you could simply use `string.Replace`:

```
"you your".Replace("you", "YOU");
```

However, this is case sensitive. If you want to have it case insensitive, you could use regex:

```
string B = "YOU";
string A = "you your";
var regex = new Regex( B, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
var newA = regex.Replace( A, B);
```

If you want mulitple items to get replaced, simply do this for every replace item.

For more information on `Replace`, take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx. The regex idea is from here: [How to ignore case in String.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025560/how-to-ignore-case-in-string-replace), you can get more information on `Regex.Replace` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx.