# String.Replace ignoring case

Tags: c#, string

I have a string called "hello world"

I need to replace the word "world" to "csharp"

for this I use:

```
string.Replace("World", "csharp");
```

but as a result, I don't get the string replaced. The reason is case sensitiveness. The original string contains "world" whereas I'm trying to replace "World".

Is there any way to avoid this case sensitiveness in string.Replace method?

Comment: Here you find similiar problem:      [Is there an alternative to string.Replace that is case-insensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative to string.Replace that is case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive)

Comment: It is a shame that Microsoft did not implement such a basic functionality into the framework!

Comment: For .NET 5 and recent versions of .NET Core, just use the overload of string.Replace that takes a StringComparison as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64677285/

Answer (score 396, accepted):

You could use a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) and perform a case insensitive replace:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "hello WoRlD";
        string result = 
           Regex.Replace(input, "world", "csharp", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Console.WriteLine(result); // prints "hello csharp"
    }
}
```

Comment: Not works with **Regex language elements**, so it's not universal method. Steve B's answer is correct.

Comment: So you better don't write `hello. world?` or anything else containing regex operators.

Comment: Just in case anyone wasn't inclined to read further, this was the accepted answer in 2011 and has a huge number of votes.  This works fine if you only have to replace alphanumeric.  However, if you have to replace any punctuation characters you can get into big trouble.  Oleg Zarevennyi's answer is superior, but has only a small number of votes because it was posted in 2017.

Comment: Replace with $$ doesn't work.  If your replacement can contain $$ then go with Oleg's solution.

Comment: Regex is too complicated. It's really just the worst. The learning curve is high *just* to get started, and even far higher to actually be good at it. So most people just go to the internet to copy/paste well tested Regex expressions. And even THEN they often aren't perfect. Try looking for the perfect Regex for email and you'll see what I mean. It has its uses, particularly in declarative contexts such as IIS Rewrite Rules where you can't use procedural logic. But I have absolutely zero use for it in c# where I can write perfectly readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 149):

```
var search = "world";
var replacement = "csharp";
string result = Regex.Replace(
    stringToLookInto,
    Regex.Escape(search), 
    replacement.Replace("$","$$"), 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

The [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) is useful if you rely on user input which can contains [Regex language elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az24scfc.aspx)

**Update**

Thanks to comments, you actually don't have to escape the replacement string.

[Here is a small fiddle that tests the code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zuDrT2):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;           
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var tests = new[] {
            new { Input="abcdef", Search="abc", Replacement="xyz", Expected="xyzdef" },
            new { Input="ABCdef", Search="abc", Replacement="xyz", Expected="xyzdef" },
            new { Input="A*BCdef", Search="a*bc", Replacement="xyz", Expected="xyzdef" },
            new { Input="abcdef", Search="abc", Replacement="x*yz", Expected="x*yzdef" },       
            new { Input="abcdef", Search="abc", Replacement="$", Expected="$def" },
        };


        foreach(var test in tests){
            var result = ReplaceCaseInsensitive(test.Input, test.Search, test.Replacement);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "Success: {0}, Actual: {1}, {2}",
                result == test.Expected,
                result,
                test
            );

        }


    }

    private static string ReplaceCaseInsensitive(string input, string search, string replacement){
        string result = Regex.Replace(
            input,
            Regex.Escape(search), 
            replacement.Replace("$","$$"), 
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        );
        return result;
    }
}
```

Its output is:

```
Success: True, Actual: xyzdef, { Input = abcdef, Search = abc, Replacement = xyz, Expected = xyzdef } 
Success: True, Actual: xyzdef, { Input = ABCdef, Search = abc, Replacement = xyz, Expected = xyzdef }
Success: True, Actual: xyzdef, { Input = A*BCdef, Search = a*bc, Replacement = xyz, Expected = xyzdef } 
Success: True, Actual: x*yzdef, { Input = abcdef, Search = abc, Replacement = x*yz, Expected = x*yzdef} 
Success: True, Actual: $def, { Input = abcdef, Search = abc, Replacement = $, Expected = $def }
```

Comment: This method fails if replacement = "!@#$%^&*()"  You get "!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)" replaced instead.

Comment: The second `Regex.Escape` is bad, it will prefix special characters with backslashes. Seems like the best way is .Replace("$", "$$"), which is kinda dumb (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10078353).

Comment: @dannyTuppeny: you are right... I updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 110):

**2.5X FASTER** and **MOST EFFECTIVE** method than other's regular expressions methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another 
/// specified string according the type of search to use for the specified string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">The string performing the replace method.</param>
/// <param name="oldValue">The string to be replaced.</param>
/// <param name="newValue">The string replace all occurrences of <paramref name="oldValue"/>. 
/// If value is equal to <c>null</c>, than all occurrences of <paramref name="oldValue"/> will be removed from the <paramref name="str"/>.</param>
/// <param name="comparisonType">One of the enumeration values that specifies the rules for the search.</param>
/// <returns>A string that is equivalent to the current string except that all instances of <paramref name="oldValue"/> are replaced with <paramref name="newValue"/>. 
/// If <paramref name="oldValue"/> is not found in the current instance, the method returns the current instance unchanged.</returns>
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static string Replace(this string str,
    string oldValue, string newValue,
    StringComparison comparisonType)
{

    // Check inputs.
    if (str == null)
    {
        // Same as original .NET C# string.Replace behavior.
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
    }
    if (oldValue == null)
    {
        // Same as original .NET C# string.Replace behavior.
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(oldValue));
    }
    if (oldValue.Length == 0)
    {
        // Same as original .NET C# string.Replace behavior.
        throw new ArgumentException("String cannot be of zero length.");
    }
    if (str.Length == 0)
    {
        // Same as original .NET C# string.Replace behavior.
        return str;
    }
    

    //if (oldValue.Equals(newValue, comparisonType))
    //{
    //This condition has no sense
    //It will prevent method from replacesing: "Example", "ExAmPlE", "EXAMPLE" to "example"
    //return str;
    //}



    // Prepare string builder for storing the processed string.
    // Note: StringBuilder has a better performance than String by 30-40%.
    StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(str.Length);



    // Analyze the replacement: replace or remove.
    bool isReplacementNullOrEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue);



    // Replace all values.
    const int valueNotFound = -1;
    int foundAt;
    int startSearchFromIndex = 0;
    while ((foundAt = str.IndexOf(oldValue, startSearchFromIndex, comparisonType)) != valueNotFound)
    {
        
        // Append all characters until the found replacement.
        int charsUntilReplacment = foundAt - startSearchFromIndex;
        bool isNothingToAppend = charsUntilReplacment == 0;
        if (!isNothingToAppend)
        {
            resultStringBuilder.Append(str, startSearchFromIndex, charsUntilReplacment);
        }
        


        // Process the replacement.
        if (!isReplacementNullOrEmpty)
        {
            resultStringBuilder.Append(newValue);
        }
        

        // Prepare start index for the next search.
        // This needed to prevent infinite loop, otherwise method always start search 
        // from the start of the string. For example: if an oldValue == "EXAMPLE", newValue == "example"
        // and comparisonType == "any ignore case" will conquer to replacing:
        // "EXAMPLE" to "example" to "example" to "example" … infinite loop.
        startSearchFromIndex = foundAt + oldValue.Length;
        if (startSearchFromIndex == str.Length)
        {
            // It is end of the input string: no more space for the next search.
            // The input string ends with a value that has already been replaced. 
            // Therefore, the string builder with the result is complete and no further action is required.
            return resultStringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
    

    // Append the last part to the result.
    int charsUntilStringEnd = str.Length - startSearchFromIndex;
    resultStringBuilder.Append(str, startSearchFromIndex, charsUntilStringEnd);


    return resultStringBuilder.ToString();

}
```

**Note: ignore case** == `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as parameter for `StringComparison comparisonType`. It is the fastest, case-insensitive way to replace all values.

---

Advantages of this method:

- High CPU and MEMORY efficiency;
- It is the fastest solution, 2.5 times faster than other's methods
  with regular expressions (proof in the end);
- Suitable for removing parts from the input string (set `newValue` to
  `null`), optimized for this;
- Same as original *.NET C#* `string.Replace` behavior, same exceptions;
- Well commented, easy to understand;
- Simpler – no regular expressions. Regular expressions are always slower  because of their versatility (even compiled);
- This method is well tested and there are no hidden flaws like infinite loop in other's solutions, even highly rated:

> @AsValeO: Not works with Regex language elements, so it's not
> universal method

> @Mike Stillion: There is a problem with this code. If the text in new
> is a superset of the text in old, this can produce an endless loop.

---

**Benchmark-proof**: this solution is **2.59X** times faster than regex from @Steve B., code:

```
// Results:
// 1/2. Regular expression solution: 4486 milliseconds
// 2/2. Current solution: 1727 milliseconds — 2.59X times FASTER! than regex!

// Notes: the test was started 5 times, the result is an average; release build.

const int benchmarkIterations = 1000000;
const string sourceString = "aaaaddsdsdsdsdsd";
const string oldValue = "D";
const string newValue = "Fod";
long totalLenght = 0;

Stopwatch regexStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
string tempString1;
for (int i = 0; i < benchmarkIterations; i++)
{
    tempString1 = sourceString;
    tempString1 = ReplaceCaseInsensitive(tempString1, oldValue, newValue);

    totalLenght = totalLenght + tempString1.Length;
}
regexStopwatch.Stop();



Stopwatch currentSolutionStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
string tempString2;
for (int i = 0; i < benchmarkIterations; i++)
{
    tempString2 = sourceString;
    tempString2 = tempString2.Replace(oldValue, newValue,
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    totalLenght = totalLenght + tempString2.Length;
}
currentSolutionStopwatch.Stop();
```

---

Original idea – @Darky711; thanks @MinerR for `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I bet you can make this even faster using a StringBuilder rather than a string.

Comment: @MineR You are right, I originally just updated the @Darky711 solution without infinite loop, so I used the `String`.  However, the `StringBuilder` is really faster by **30-40%** than the `String`. I've updated the solution. Thanks ;)

Comment: Interesting approach. Probably the better one (better than mine :)) when performance matters. Typically a method to add to a common shared code library.

Comment: The use of 'nameof' expressions makes this valid only for C# 6.0 and beyond.  If you're in VS2013, you can use it by simply deleting the operands in the exceptions.

Comment: For the commented out "//if (oldValue.Equals(newValue, comparisonType))"  replace comparisonType with StringComparison.Ordinal?

Comment: You have a bug when calling replace("abc","abc\u00AD","def",StringComparison.CurrentCulture) the expected result is "def" (\u00AD is a soft hyphen - test case taken from .net core string replace test cases at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1bfdab43807670a7fba468d09b9afd1a72d1f8e3/src/libraries/System.Runtime/tests/System/StringTests.cs ). The fix is to change "if (startSearchFromIndex == str.Length)" to "if (startSearchFromIndex >= str.Length)"

Comment: It doesn't yield the same result. When done with ignore case this method replaces the lower cased string while the method of @Darin Dimitrov replaces the original cased string.

Comment: Aside from the obvious spelling error in `charsUntilReplacment`, why the `isNothingToAppend` variable?  You use it only in the `if` statement that immediately follows its creation, so why not just put the condition directly in the `if`?

Comment: @LanchPad What about just putting literal `"str"` and `"oldValue"` there?

Answer (score 37):

Lots of suggestions using Regex. How about this extension method without it:

```
public static string Replace(this string str, string old, string @new, StringComparison comparison)
{
    @new = @new ?? "";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(old) || old.Equals(@new, comparison))
        return str;
    int foundAt = 0;
    while ((foundAt = str.IndexOf(old, foundAt, comparison)) != -1)
    {
        str = str.Remove(foundAt, old.Length).Insert(foundAt, @new);
        foundAt += @new.Length;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Note that the comparison argument is not being used to do the actual replacement (it is always case insensitive)

Comment: There is a problem with this code.  If the text in **new** is a superset of the text in **old**, this can produce an endless loop.  Once **new** is inserted at **FoundAt**, the value of **FoundAt** needs to be advanced by the length of **new**.

Comment: `comparison` parameter should be used in `IndexOf`, instead of `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`

Comment: @Bolo I've edited it to use the comparison argument (might take a bit to be peer reviewed).

Comment: I fixed the **infinite loop** problem of this method. Increase speed by **30-40%** by replacing `String` with `StringBuilder`. And add missed comments. Please check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756981/1998097

Comment: I'd also separate this condition for returning the new string: `if(old.Equals(@new, comparison)) return @new;`, since the new string may differ in uppercase/lowercase.

Comment: honestly, @new hurts my eyes

Answer (score 34):

Extensions make our lives easier:

```
static public class StringExtensions
{
    static public string ReplaceInsensitive(this string str, string from, string to)
    {
        str = Regex.Replace(str, from, to, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: And escaping makes our lives less buggy :-)
return Regex.Replace(input, Regex.Escape(search), replacement.Replace("$", "$$"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 25):

.Net Core has this method built-in:
`Replace(String, String, StringComparison)` [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-2.2#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_StringComparison_). Now we can simply write:
`"...".Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Works flawlessly in .NET 8, too

Answer (score 19):

You can use the **Microsoft.VisualBasic** namespace to find this helper function:

```
Replace(sourceString, "replacethis", "withthis", , , CompareMethod.Text)
```

Comment: I was proud of my answer until I saw this which is a better answer because it is built in. Ex: Strings.Replace("TeStInG123", "t", "z", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Text) returns "zeSzInG123"

Comment: Warning, Strings.Replace returns null if the string being search is an empty string.

Comment: In .Net 4.7.2, you need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic to get this to work.  In .Net Core, the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings class (in Version 10.3.0 anyway) does not appear to implement the Replace function.  This works in Powershell as well if you Add-Class -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic first.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it makes a copy of the entire string even if nothing is replaced, so it can be very bulky. I rewrote it to not do that a while back, since strings are immutable.

Answer (score 8):

Modified @Darky711's answer to use the passed in comparison type and match the framework replace naming and xml comments as closely as possible.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">The string performing the replace method.</param>
/// <param name="oldValue">The string to be replaced.</param>
/// <param name="newValue">The string replace all occurrances of oldValue.</param>
/// <param name="comparisonType">Type of the comparison.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Replace(this string str, string oldValue, string @newValue, StringComparison comparisonType)
{
    @newValue = @newValue ?? string.Empty;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue) || oldValue.Equals(@newValue, comparisonType))
    {
        return str;
    }
    int foundAt;
    while ((foundAt = str.IndexOf(oldValue, 0, comparisonType)) != -1)
    {
        str = str.Remove(foundAt, oldValue.Length).Insert(foundAt, @newValue);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

(**Edited:** wasn't aware of the `naked link' problem, sorry about that)

Taken from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2004/02/11/71188.aspx):

```
string myString = "find Me and replace ME";
string strReplace = "me";
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "me", strReplace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Seems you are not the first to complain of the lack of case insensitive string.Replace.

Answer (score 3):

Extending [Petrucio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828681/petrucio)'s answer with [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) on the search string, and escaping matched group as suggested in [Steve B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588868/steve-b)'s answer (and some minor changes to my taste):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceIgnoreCase(this string str, string from, string to)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(str, Regex.Escape(from), to.Replace("$", "$$"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Which will produce the following expected results:

```
Console.WriteLine("(heLLo) wOrld".ReplaceIgnoreCase("(hello) world", "Hi $1 Universe")); // Hi $1 Universe
Console.WriteLine("heLLo wOrld".ReplaceIgnoreCase("(hello) world", "Hi $1 Universe"));   // heLLo wOrld
```

However without performing the escapes you would get the following, which is not an expected behaviour from a `String.Replace` that is just case-insensitive:

```
Console.WriteLine("(heLLo) wOrld".ReplaceIgnoreCase_NoEscaping("(hello) world", "Hi $1 Universe")); // (heLLo) wOrld
Console.WriteLine("heLLo wOrld".ReplaceIgnoreCase_NoEscaping("(hello) world", "Hi $1 Universe"));   // Hi heLLo Universe
```

Answer (score 3):

I have wrote extension method:

```
public static string ReplaceIgnoreCase(this string source, string oldVale, string newVale)
    {
        if (source.IsNullOrEmpty() || oldVale.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return source;

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string result = source;

        int index = result.IndexOf(oldVale, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        while (index >= 0)
        {
            if (index > 0)
                stringBuilder.Append(result.Substring(0, index));

            if (newVale.IsNullOrEmpty().IsNot())
                stringBuilder.Append(newVale);

            stringBuilder.Append(result.Substring(index + oldVale.Length));

            result = stringBuilder.ToString();

            index = result.IndexOf(oldVale, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I use two additional extension methods for previous extension method:

```
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }

    public static bool IsNot(this bool val)
    {
        return val == false;
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted. But `IsNot` is taking extensions too seriously :)

Comment: Disappointing, this does not work in all situations. I was passing a distinguished name and it appends until the string is a million characters long and then runs out of memory

Comment: Alternative offered below that fixed my issue

Comment: I really like `.IsNot`

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't this work: I cant imaging anything else being much quicker or easier.

```
public static class ExtensionMethodsString
{
    public static string Replace(this String thisString, string oldValue, string newValue, StringComparison stringComparison)
    {
        string working = thisString;
        int index = working.IndexOf(oldValue, stringComparison);
        while (index != -1)
        {
            working = working.Remove(index, oldValue.Length);
            working = working.Insert(index, newValue);
            index = index + newValue.Length;
            index = working.IndexOf(oldValue, index, stringComparison);
        }
        return working;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's faster but it's concise, doesn't use regex overhead and potential problems and uses the built-in StringComparison.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to ignore the case sensitivity in String.Replace() using the option **StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase**

```
string.Replace("World", "csharp", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: This is entirely valid, *but* requires modern frameworks - that *we should already be using*; I'm guessing the downvote was from a .NET Framework user (it exists in .NET Core 2 and later, and .NET Standard 2.1) - or it could be an observation that it duplicates an existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64677285/23354

Answer (score 1):

Using @Georgy Batalov solution I had a problem when using the following example

string original = "blah,DC=bleh,DC=blih,DC=bloh,DC=com";
string replaced = original.ReplaceIgnoreCase(",DC=", ".")

Below is how I rewrote his extension

```
public static string ReplaceIgnoreCase(this string source, string oldVale, 
string newVale)
    {
        if (source.IsNullOrEmpty() || oldVale.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return source;

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string result = source;

        int index = result.IndexOf(oldVale, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        bool initialRun = true;

        while (index >= 0)
        {
            string substr = result.Substring(0, index);
            substr = substr + newVale;
            result = result.Remove(0, index);
            result = result.Remove(0, oldVale.Length);

            stringBuilder.Append(substr);

            index = result.IndexOf(oldVale, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        if (result.Length > 0)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(result);
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**My this Method could Ignore Case as well as Select Only Whole Word**

```
public static string Replace(this string s, string word, string by, StringComparison stringComparison, bool WholeWord)
{
    s = s + " ";
    int wordSt;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (s.IndexOf(word, stringComparison) > -1)
    {
        wordSt = s.IndexOf(word, stringComparison);
        if (!WholeWord || ((wordSt == 0 || !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(char.Parse(s.Substring(wordSt - 1, 1)))) && !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(char.Parse(s.Substring(wordSt + word.Length, 1)))))
        {
            sb.Append(s.Substring(0, wordSt) + by);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(s.Substring(0, wordSt + word.Length));
        }
        s = s.Substring(wordSt + word.Length);
    }
    sb.Append(s);
    return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase method as proposed by ZZY / Gama Sharma.  This is just another technique that could be used with LINQ:

> ```
> List<string> ItemsToRedact = new List<string> { "star", "citizen", "test", "universe"};
>
> string Message = "Just like each sTaR is unique yet mAkes the uniVERSE what it is, the light in you makes you who you are";
>
> List<string> ReplacementList = Message.Split(' ').Where(x => ItemsToRedact.Contains(x.ToLower())).ToList();
>
> foreach (var word in ReplacementList)
> {
>      Message = Message.Replace(word, "[Redacted] ");
> }
>
> Console.WriteLine(Message);
> ```

returns: Just like each [Redacted]  is unique yet mAkes the [Redacted]  what it is, the light in you makes you who you are

This code could be further distilled but I broke it up for readability

Comment: This solution has at least two bugs. 1 - redacted words would contain an extra trailing space because this solution replaces a word (without a trailing space) with "[Redacted] " (with a trailing space). 2 - words containing part of a matched word would be replaced with "[Redacted] ". For example, if the Message was "sTaRt the sTaR forge" and "star" was being redacted, then the result would be "s[Redacted]  the [Redacted]  forge".

Answer (score 0):

Below function is to remove all match word like (this) from the string set. By Ravikant Sonare.

```
private static void myfun()
{
    string mystring = "thiTHISThiss This THIS THis tThishiThiss. Box";
    var regex = new Regex("this", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    mystring = regex.Replace(mystring, "");
    string[] str = mystring.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (regex.IsMatch(str[i].ToString()))
        {
            mystring = mystring.Replace(str[i].ToString(), string.Empty);

        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(mystring);
}
```

Comment: This function is replace all string from the the string set ... by Ravikant Sonare,

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `Regex` class.

`var regex = new Regex( "camel", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
var newSentence = regex.Replace( sentence, "horse" );`

Answer (score 0):

Use this, Tested and 100% Worked!

For VB.NET

```
Dim myString As String
Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String

myString = Form1.TextBox1.Text
oldValue = TextBox1.Text
newValue = TextBox2.Text

Dim working As String = myString
Dim index As Integer = working.IndexOf(oldValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

While index <> -1
    working = working.Remove(index, oldValue.Length)
    working = working.Insert(index, newValue)
    index = index + newValue.Length
    index = working.IndexOf(oldValue, index, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    Form1.TextBox1.Text = working
End While
```

For C#

```
private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string myString;
    string oldValue;
    string newValue;

    myString = Form1.TextBox1.Text;
    oldValue = TextBox1.Text;
    newValue = TextBox2.Text;

    string working = myString;
    int index = working.IndexOf(oldValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    while (index != -1)
    {
        working = working.Remove(index, oldValue.Length);
        working = working.Insert(index, newValue);
        index = index + newValue.Length;
        index = working.IndexOf(oldValue, index, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        Form1.TextBox1.Text = working;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the previous answer has mentioned the most simplest way, and effective by the way, to do it.

As you can see int he [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-8.0#system-string-replace(system-string-system-string-system-boolean-system-globalization-cultureinfo)) the .NET you have the possibility to pass more than 2 parameters, so if you want to replace the text "test" by the text "It works!" ignoring case, you can do something as simple as this:

```
var initialText = "This is a Test";
initialText.Replace("test","It works!", true, null);
```

The last parameter is a boolean that indicate to ignore case sensitive or not, in this case as we are ignoring it, it will replace the text even when the original text starts with capital letter.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer this - "Hello World".ToLower().Replace( "world", "csharp" );

Comment: This will lowercase everything, even words that weren't supposed to be replaced.

Comment: Obviously, you can use this only if you are not bothered about the case.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer for simple use of the Replace method in most cases, despite all of the down votes. If you are doing an edge case that is more complex, then you probably should not be using Replace() to begin with.