# Handling regex escape replacement text that contains the dollar character

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

```
string input = "Hello World!";
string pattern = "(World|Universe)";
string replacement = "$1";

string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Having the following example, the result would be `"Hello World!"`, as the `$1` gets replaced with the first group `(World|Universe)`, however the result I want is `"Hello $1!"`

The `Regex.Escape` method is meant to be used to escape a Regex pattern, not the replacement, as it can escape other characters like slashes and other Regex pattern characters.  The obvious fix to my problem is to have my replacement equal to `"$$1"`, and will achieve `"Hello $1!"`, but I was wondering if the dollar sign is the only value I have to escape (assuming `replacement` is user generated, and I do not know it ahead of time), or is there a helper function that does this already.

Does anyone know of a function to escape the replacement value that `Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, string replacement)` uses?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx):

> The *replacement* parameter specifies the string that is to replace each match in *input*. *replacement* can consist of any combination of literal text and [substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx).

The following substitutions [are defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx):

- $number
- ${name}
- $$
- $&
- $`
- $'
- $+
- $_

> Substitutions are the only special constructs recognized in a replacement pattern. None of the other regular expression language elements, including character escapes and the period (.), which matches any character, are supported. Similarly, substitution language elements are recognized only in replacement patterns and are never valid in regular expression patterns.

So it look like it's only the $ character that needs to be escaped.

Comment: Also from MSDN: Substitutions are the only regular expression language elements that are recognized in a replacement pattern. All other regular expression language elements, including character escapes, are allowed in regular expression patterns only and are not recognized in replacement patterns.

Comment: This looks good enough for me, I suspect doing a dumb ol' `replacement.Replace("$", "$$")` should be good 100% of the time then?

Comment: Yes, `replacement.Replace("$", "$$")` should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe, it also makes sense that we create a string extension method, like `public string EscapeRegexReplacement(this string replacement)    { return replacement.Replace("$", "$$"); }` and keep it somewhere in a global utility project in our solution so that it can be reused wherever required. Also feels like Microsoft should have included a static function in `Regex` class themselves, like they have `Regex.Escape`.