# How to escape the substitution/replacement part in .NET Regex Replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace, substitution

I want to escape the substitution part in a regex replace command in .NET:

```
public static string GetPriceMessage(string data, string price)
{
    var repl = "This is a $1 priced at " + price + " suitable for $2.";
    return Regex.Replace(data, "item_name: ([^;]+); suitable: ([^;]+)", repl);
}

var price = "$15/item";
var data = "item_name: Puzzle; suitable: all ages";

GetPriceMessage(data, price)
```

I want to make sure `price` is substituted verbatim. `Regex.Escape` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to escape `$` in substitutions, since all substitutions start with `$`. I.e. just use:

```
price.Replace("$", "$$");
```

See the following question for details: [Handling regex escape replacement text that contains the dollar character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078230/regex-escape-replacement-text)

> Substitutions are the only regular expression language elements that are recognized in a replacement pattern. All other regular expression language elements, including character escapes, are allowed in regular expression patterns only and are not recognized in replacement patterns.

[...]

> In a replacement pattern, $ indicates the beginning of a substitution.

Comment: Or just change `string price = "$15/item" ;` to `string price = "$$15/item" ;`