# Replace Exact matching string using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my code snippet:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SafeReplace(this string input, string find, string replace, bool matchWholeWord)
    {
        string textToFind = matchWholeWord ? string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", find) : find;
        return Regex.Replace(input, textToFind, replace);
    }
}
selectColumns = selectColumns.SafeReplace("RegistrantData.HomePhone","RegistrantData.HomePhoneAreaCode + '-' + RegistrantData.HomePhonePrefix + '-' + RegistrantData.HomePhoneSuffix", true);
```

However this also replaces the string "RegistrantData_HomePhone".
How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape the text:

```
string textToFind = matchWholeWord ? string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(find)) : Regex.Escape(find);
```

[Regex.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) will replace (for example) `.` (of `RegistrantData**.**HomePhone)`with `\.` (and many other sequences)

It could be a good idea to

```
return Regex.Replace(input, textToFind, replace.Replace("$", "$$"));
```

because the `$` has a special meaning in `Regex.Replace` (See [Handling regex escape replacement text that contains the dollar character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078230/handling-regex-escape-replacement-text-that-contains-the-dollar-character)). Note that for replacement you can't use `Regex.Escape`.