# How do you use a $ in a Regex.Replace string

Tags: c#, regex

Assuming `string x = "$5."` I have something like this

```
x = Regex.Replace(x, @"(^\$?\d{0,4}\.?$)", "$$1.00");
```

Expecting `x` to be `"$5.00"` but I get `"$$1.00"`.
This

```
x = Regex.Replace(x, @"(^\$?\d{0,4}\.?$)", "@$1.00");
```

Yields `"@5.00"`

How can I use a `$` in the replacement?

Comment: For your replacement text, you must replace `$` with `$$`.  The `$$` represents a single dollar sign.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078230/handling-regex-escape-replacement-text-that-contains-the-dollar-character

Comment: You can test using online tester. May be helpful to you. http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: `x = Regex.Replace(x, @"(^\$?\d{0,4})\.?$", "$1.00");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be *triple* `$$$`:

```
x = Regex.Replace(x, @"^\$?(\d{0,4})\.?$", "$$$1.00");
```

Here we preserve *integer part* `^\$?(\d{0,4})` as a group #1 which we use in replace - `$1` and add dollar sign `$$` with fractional part -  `.00`

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ym2iPZ)

Comment: Problem is what if the input is 5.00?

Comment: Your comment in Recep Selli's answer is what I was looking for. e.g. "$$ stands for the dollar sign"

Comment: @user1604008: if you want ever put `$` (`5.` => `$5.00` as well as `5.` => `$5.00`) you should use *triple* `$$$`: `$$` for dollar sign, `$1` for substitution. Please, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Regex.Replace(x, @"(^\$?\d{0,4}\.?$)", "$1.00");
```

This should replace the match with the captured value followed by .00, resulting in $5.00.

Comment: Your code returns `$5..00` (note *double* decimal point`.`)