# string.replace() not working with xml string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string, replace

I have read all similar questions and acted accordingly. But still can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

This is my code, super simple. (I know this isn't valid XML. It's just for the example).

```
string replacement = "TimeSheetsReplaced";
string word = "TimeSheets";
string result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><DisplayName>Timesheets</DisplayName>"; 
result = result.Replace("<DisplayName>" + word + "</DisplayName>", "<DisplayName>" + replacement + "</DisplayName>");
```

The result string remains unplaced. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Why not just parse the XML using the classes in `System.XML`, modify the value properly and write it back out again?

Comment: time sheets has a capital s in word and not in result, but @PhonicUK's suggestion is correct way to do this..

Comment: Case sensitivity in strings...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6276004/284240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimeSheets != Timesheets`

Casing does not match

Comment: awesome! we answered in the exact same second :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your string contains `Timesheets`, but you're lokoing for `TimeSheets` (with a capital `S`).

Answer (score 0):

In your word TimeSheets has big S, in string small s