# Fastest way to replace multiple strings in a huge string

Tags: c#, string, performance, replace

I'm looking for the fastest way to replace multiple (~500) substrings of a big (~1mb) string. Whatever I have tried it seems that String.Replace is the fastest way of doing it.

I just care about the fastest possible way. Not code readability, maintainability etc. I don't care if I need to use unsafe code or pre-process the original string either.

Each replace iteration will replace ABC on the string with some other string (different per replace iteration). The string to replace will ALWAYS be the same - ABC will always be ABC. Never ABD. So if there are `400.000` thousands replace iterations. The same string - ABC - will be replaced with some other (different) string each time.

I can be in control of what ABC is. I can make it super-short or super-long as long as it doesn't affect the results. Clearly ABC can't be *hello* cause hello will exist as a word in most of the input strings.

Example input: `ABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCD`

Example replace from string: `BC`

Example replace with strings: `AA, BB, CC, DD, EE (5 iterations)`

Example outputs:

```
AAADAAAAAADAAAAAADAAAAAADAAAD
ABBDABBABBDABBABBDABBABBDABBD
ACCDACCACCDACCACCDACCACCDACCD
ADDDADDADDDADDADDDADDADDDADDD
AEEDAEEAEEDAEEAEEDAEEAEEDAEED
```

**Average case:** Input string is 100-200kb with 40.000 replace iterations.
Worst case: Input string is 1-2mb with 400.000 replace iterations.

I can do ANYTHING. Do it in parallel, do it unsafe, etc. It doesn't matter how I do it. What matters is that it needs to be as fast as it gets.

Comment: You could look at handling chunks at a time, but String.Replace would be the way to go. Can you give us more context?

Comment: What would you like to know? Imagine a big string. I can be in control of the format/length of sub-strings to replace (e.g. #abc# instead of abc or 123 etc). But this is an operation that will happen thousands of times on the same string with the same keys but different replacement values.

Comment: Give us an example with input and expected output.

Comment: can you alter the data structure holding the text? can you use parallel threads?

Comment: since it is an optimization issue, please explain what is the average and worst input string, and what is the average and worst substrings. If it's only about replacing a 1 or 2 char long string, the issue will be very different from replacing very long strings.

Comment: *Whatever I have tried it seems that String.Replace is the fastest way of doing it.* It sounds like `String.Replace` is the fastest way of doing it....

Comment: What are you doing with the strings once they've been generated? For optimization, you always have to look at the whole system, not just a part of it.

Comment: @Yannis, how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Also, the [regex] tag is a red herring, I'm removing it.

Comment: "I just care about the fastest possible way. Not code readability, maintainability etc. I dont care if I need to use unsafe code or pre-process the original string either." You could spend the rest of your life making a better and better algorithm. There is no fastest way to do anything, how fast is it now? And how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Will the replacing string always be as long as the replaced string? That would save tons of time creating arrays and coping data. Also it could help if you have many texts that need to be replaced in the same source? Then the search machine could search for all of them at the same time, that could replace all in one iteration.

Comment: @dtb other components have already been heavily optimized. The String.Replace is where I spend sometihng like 80% of my time in the application.

Comment: @MrFox As mentioned in another comment. The String.Replace is where I spend sometihng like 80% of my time in the application. You understand that if I lets say make it faster by 20% then the whole program becomes 15-16% faster. You get the idea.

Comment: @Yannis Yea that comment was a bit whiny, could you comment on the operation properties I asked about later on? Those could make some big optimizations possible.

Comment: Do you definitely need the result as a string, rather than (say) a char array? If you can decide the delimiter beforehand, and it will never occur in the real string, do you really need the string in one chunk? It feels like you've naturally just got chunks. It would really help if you'd describe more of the *purpose* of this...

Comment: Is this an attempt to change a DNA? :)

Comment: Do you want to keep all of the results in memory? Looking at your worst case scenario: 2Mb with 400 000 replacements means 800 000Mb (781.25Gb) worth of data in memory for the results

Comment: Also, if you're truly interested in performance, would you be apposed to solutions in other languages? This would be a great task for CUDA, although I'm not sure it would actually be faster with all the marshalling back and forth between managed and native

Comment: @Laurent - No. Although the example makes it seem like it is. Its a general question about templating a long string.

Comment: @flipchart - Results aren't stored in memory. In fact, after some replacements they get persisted. That bit is already optimized. So no - I dont have to neither I do keep all results in memory.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I have tried the char array and essentially doing a char[].replace (in a way). I dont think thats the faster option though. But I agree that the overhead of using strings is not necessary here.

Comment: Has someone tried to use a lex/yacc approach in this case ?

Comment: It *does* look like DNA modelling: exactly 4 bases, very long strings, rule based substitutions... the only other bell it rings is one time xor pads. Hey, you aren't using steganography to hide xor pads in what otherwise appears to be DNA data? It's intriguing that you're so concerned with speed; of all the applications I can imagine, only cryptography is so time sensitive.

Comment: @PeterWone - Why would I lie that its not DNA? Its not like I have my DNA sequence in the example above and you were planning to clone me or something. I m concerned about speed cause the application in discussion spends 80% of the time (after all other optimizations) replacing sub-strings of strings. Also, I never said that I have 4 bases. If you read the detailed description above you have thousands of replace operations.

Comment: @yannis - I didn't say that and I didn't insinuate anything of the sort. I'm sorry you got that impression.

Comment: Almost certainly, the fastest way would be an unsafe C++ string Transducer based on either Boyer-Moore or KMP searching.

Answer (score 4):

Using `unsafe` and compiled as x64

result:

```
Implementation       | Exec   | GC
#1 Simple            | 4706ms |  0ms
#2 Simple parallel   | 2265ms |  0ms
#3 ParallelSubstring |  800ms | 21ms
#4 Fredou unsafe     |  432ms | 15ms
```

take the code of `Erti-Chris Eelmaa` and replace my previous one with this.

I don't think I will do another iteration but i did learn a few thing with unsafe which is a good thing :-)

```
    private unsafe static void FredouImplementation(string input, int inputLength, string replace, string[] replaceBy)
    {
        var indexes = new List<int>();

        //input = "ABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCD";
        //inputLength = input.Length;
        //replaceBy = new string[] { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE" };

        //my own string.indexof to save a few ms
        int len = inputLength;

        fixed (char* i = input, r = replace)
        {
            int replaceValAsInt = *((int*)r);

            while (--len > -1)
            {
                if (replaceValAsInt == *((int*)&i[len]))
                {
                    indexes.Add(len--);
                }
            }                
        }

        var idx = indexes.ToArray();
        len = indexes.Count;

        Parallel.For(0, replaceBy.Length, l =>
            Process(input, inputLength, replaceBy[l], idx, len)
        );
    }

    private unsafe static void Process(string input, int len, string replaceBy, int[] idx, int idxLen)
    {
        var output = new char[len];

        fixed (char* o = output, i = input, r = replaceBy)
        {
            int replaceByValAsInt = *((int*)r);

            //direct copy, simulate string.copy
            while (--len > -1)
            {
                o[len] = i[len];
            }

            while (--idxLen > -1)
            {
                ((int*)&o[idx[idxLen]])[0] = replaceByValAsInt;
            }
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

Comment: im going to look at unsafe later today :-)

Comment: about 33% faster with unsafe

Comment: That's nice. I see you're doing some things, such as declaring variables outside loop, so they wouldn't get repeated(such as by/inputLength) - does this actually win you some milliseconds? I am wondering because one would expect C# compiler do the magic, but what I've seen, it really doesn't do such simple things. I can only suggest you to implement substring parallelization too, and see if you can get it even faster than 250ms or so. My #3d solution focuses too much time in GC, I will try to declare them "globally" as you do(output)

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa you need to look at the il produced to know why i'm moving the variable inside the parallel loop

Comment: This is a VERY good solution @Fredou - Will keep you posted! Quick q for now. Why are you iterating 5 times in your solution (where you do the parallel.for)?

Comment: @Fredou your solution is very good but unfortunately it doesnt work for variable length replacements. For instance "ABCDEFG".Replace("AB", "FREDOU") == false

Comment: @Yannis, it is "hardcoded" to be a 2 chars replacement only, i will see if i can make it variable

Comment: @Yannis, since you want to expand the string, I don't think the unsafe way could easily work since you have to work with fixed array size. sorry.

Comment: @Yannis, I do the loop 5 time to make sure the speed is consistent :-)

Comment: @Fredou; I have updated my post. I've upgraded it to 1MB string now. Note that you have to measure GC too. That means measuring the "output = new string[]" part, otherwise you're just cheating :P. If we are dealing with OP data(2MB string + 500 replacements), your solution would run out of memory, since you allocate everything at once(that is - on a 32-bit system).

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa, oops yeah your right, in one of my revision i think i moved the string.copy out of the stopwatch by mistake. im going to change(removing it in fact) it in a few minutes because this make no sense at all! thanks

Comment: in fact back in a few hour :-)

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa, took a while but i was able to fix my mistake :-) i stole your idea of doing indexof before doing the big chunk of work

Comment: Fredou, @JulianR - Erti-ChrisElmaas implementation(s) are more robust cause they allow variable size replace string (e.g. replace ABC with SOMESTRING and QWERTY with QRT). So i dont think performance comparisons between the three solutions make much sense (despite the excellent implementations)

Comment: @Yannis, since i did some major refactoring since my previous comment about expanding under unsafe, I think now I can make this work. not sure if i have time right now to make the change so i will update this in a few hours

Comment: @Fredou - Just to clarify. I dont want you to fix it :) I am just looking for the general idea here. I m just saying that comparing the results is a bit unfair but I certainly get the point.

Comment: @Yannis I like the challenge so I'm also doing it for myself :-)

Comment: @Yannis, i was able to implement a variable size find/replace but it wasn't worthed compared to Erti code so I just updated my code with a bit faster 2 chars replacement

Comment: Indeed my friends, it has been nice learning process for me too. I've added my unsafe implementation too. I see another 100ms that can be won with great tricks, but not gonna do it for now :-)

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa i'm going to have to look at the unmanaged code later today :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on a project and I've implemented a Regex solution to perform multiple **and** case insensitive replacements on a file.

For efficiency purposes, I set criteria to go through the original string **only once**.

I've published a simple console app to test some strategies on https://github.com/nmcc/Spikes/tree/master/StringMultipleReplacements

The code for the Regex solution is similar to this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    // Fill the dictionary with the proper replacements:

        StringBuilder patternBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                patternBuilder.Append('(');

                bool firstReplacement = true;

                foreach (var replacement in replacements.Keys)
                {
                    if (!firstReplacement)
                        patternBuilder.Append('|');
                    else
                        firstReplacement = false;

                    patternBuilder.Append('(');
                    patternBuilder.Append(Regex.Escape(replacement));
                    patternBuilder.Append(')');
                }
                patternBuilder.Append(')');

                var regex = new Regex(patternBuilder.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                return regex.Replace(sourceContent, new MatchEvaluator(match => replacements[match.Groups[1].Value]));
```

EDIT: The execution times running the test application on my computer are:

- Looping through the replacements calling string.Substring() (CASE SENSITIVE): 2ms
- Single pass using Regex with multiple replacements at once (Case insensitive): 8ms
- Looping through replacements using a [ReplaceIgnoreCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35644839) Extension (Case insensitive): 55ms

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are tokenising the string?
I would look at producing a buffer and indexing your tokens.
Or using a templating engine

As a naive example you could use code generation to make the following method

```
public string Produce(string tokenValue){

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("A");
    builder.Append(tokenValue);
    builder.Append("D");

    return builder.ToString();

}
```

If your running the iterations enough times, the time to build the template will pay for itself. You can then also call that method in parallel with no side effects.
Also look at interning your strings

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't get anything faster than String.Replace (unless you go native) because iirc String.Replace is implemented in CLR itself for maximum performance. If you want 100% performance, you can conveniently interface with native ASM code via C++/CLI and go from there.

Comment: It seems (at least in .NET 6) String.Replace is not implemented (any more?) in native, but in managed code:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs

Answer (score 1):

My approach is a little like templating - it takes the input string and pulls out (removes) the substrings that are to be replaced. Then it takes the remaining parts of the string (the template) and combines them with the new replacement substrings. This is done in a parallel operation (template + each replacement string), which builds the output strings.

I think what I am explaining above may be clearer with code. This uses your sample inputs from above:

```
const char splitter = '\t';   // use a char that will not appear in your string

string input = "ABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCD";
string oldString = "BC";
string[] newStrings = { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE" };

// In input, replace oldString with tabs, so that we can do String.Split later
var inputTabbed = input.Replace(oldString, splitter.ToString());
// ABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCD --> A\tDA\tA\tDA\tA\tDA\tA\tDA\tD

var inputs = inputTabbed.Split(splitter);
/* inputs (the template) now contains:
[0] "A" 
[1] "DA"
[2] "A" 
[3] "DA"
[4] "A" 
[5] "DA"
[6] "A" 
[7] "DA"
[8] "D" 
*/

// In parallel, build the output using the template (inputs)
// and the replacement strings (newStrings)
var outputs = new List<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(newStrings, iteration =>
    {
        var output = string.Join(iteration, inputs);
        // only lock the list operation
        lock (outputs) { outputs.Add(output); }
    });

foreach (var output in outputs)
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
AAADAAAAAADAAAAAADAAAAAADAAAD
ABBDABBABBDABBABBDABBABBDABBD
ACCDACCACCDACCACCDACCACCDACCD
ADDDADDADDDADDADDDADDADDDADDD
AEEDAEEAEEDAEEAEEDAEEAEEDAEED
```

So you can do a comparison, here is a complete method which can be used in the test code by Erti-Chris Eelmaa:

```
private static void TemplatingImp(string input, string replaceWhat, IEnumerable<string> replaceIterations)
{
    const char splitter = '\t';   // use a char that will not appear in your string

    var inputTabbed = input.Replace(replaceWhat, splitter.ToString());
    var inputs = inputTabbed.Split(splitter);

    // In parallel, build the output using the split parts (inputs)
    // and the replacement strings (newStrings)
    //var outputs = new List<string>();
    Parallel.ForEach(replaceIterations, iteration =>
    {
        var output = string.Join(iteration, inputs);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a variation on Fredou's code that requires less compares as it works on `int*` instead of `char*`. It still requires `n` iterations for a string of `n` length, it just has to do less comparing. You could have `n/2` iterations if the string is neatly aligned by 2 (so the string to replace can only occur at indexes 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, etc) or even `n/4` if it's aligned by 4 (you'd use `long*`). I'm not very good at bit fiddling like this, so someone might be able to find some obvious flaw in my code that could be more efficient. I verified that the result of my variation is the same as that of the simple `string.Replace`.

Additionally, I expect that some gains could be made in the 500x `string.Copy` that it does, but haven't looked into that yet.

My results (Fredou II):

```
IMPLEMENTATION       |  EXEC MS | GC MS
#1 Simple            |     6816 |     0
#2 Simple parallel   |     4202 |     0
#3 ParallelSubstring |    27839 |     4
#4 Fredou I          |     2103 |   106
#5 Fredou II         |     1334 |    91
```

So about 2/3 of the time (x86, but x64 was about the same).

For this code:

```
private unsafe struct TwoCharStringChunk
{
  public fixed char chars[2];
}

private unsafe static void FredouImplementation_Variation1(string input, int inputLength, string replace, TwoCharStringChunk[] replaceBy)
{
  var output = new string[replaceBy.Length];

  for (var i = 0; i < replaceBy.Length; ++i)
    output[i] = string.Copy(input);

  var r = new TwoCharStringChunk();
  r.chars[0] = replace[0];
  r.chars[1] = replace[1];

  _staticToReplace = r;

  Parallel.For(0, replaceBy.Length, l => Process_Variation1(output[l], input, inputLength, replaceBy[l]));
}

private static TwoCharStringChunk _staticToReplace ;

private static unsafe void Process_Variation1(string output, string input, int len, TwoCharStringChunk replaceBy)
{
  int n = 0;
  int m = len - 1;

  fixed (char* i = input, o = output, chars = _staticToReplace .chars)
  {
    var replaceValAsInt = *((int*)chars);
    var replaceByValAsInt = *((int*)replaceBy.chars);

    while (n < m)
    {
      var compareInput = *((int*)&i[n]);

      if (compareInput == replaceValAsInt)
      {
        ((int*)&o[n])[0] = replaceByValAsInt;
        n += 2;
      }
      else
      {
        ++n;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The struct with the fixed buffer is not strictly necessary here and could have been replaced with a simple `int` field, but expand the `char[2]` to `char[3]` and this code can be made to work with three letter strings as well, which wouldn't be possible if it was an `int` field.

It required some changes to the Program.cs as well, so here's the full gist:

https://gist.github.com/JulianR/7763857

EDIT: I'm not sure why my ParallelSubstring is so slow. I'm running .NET 4 in Release mode, no debugger, in either x86 or x64.

Comment: you should adapt your solution with my updated code. i don't use string.copy anymore which is freaking slow :-) I like the int32 approach. I'm still learning how to do unsafe code :-)

Comment: i did a quick test on my side and with a fixed struct of 2 char with my current solution, it save about 2-4% on runtime which seem good. i will let you do the real thing :-)

Comment: Can you fire up profiler and see why Parallel substring is so slow :P? Believe it or not, my solution is still fastest one on my computer. How many cores do you have?

Comment: I have two cores at home, but my/Fredou's implementation is multicore as well so it should scale similarly.

Answer (score 0):

As your input string can be as long as 2Mb, I don't foresee any memory allocation problem. You can load everything in memory and replace your data.

If from `BC` you ALWAYS needs to replace for `AA`, a `String.Replace` will be ok. But, if you need more control, you could use a `Regex.Replace`:

```
var input  = "ABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCABCDABCD";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "BC", (match) =>
{
    // here you can add some juice, like counters, etc
    return "AA";
});
```

Comment: I have tried that and it's actually slower than string.Replace(..)

Comment: Did you try to compile the regex?

Comment: `Regex` is not always fast. But is much more robust for strange cases.

Comment: @VitorCanova: What exactly do you mean by "much more robust"? Both `string.Replace` and `Regex.Replace` are good at doing what they're meant to do. If you're trying to replace text based on a pattern, then a regular expression is almost certainly the right approach - but if you're not using a pattern, `Replace` should be fine. What sort of case are you thinking about?

Comment: Sorry, I think a made a mistake when  I took the word "robust". What I really meant is exactly what you said. It is for more complex things. Just like `StringBuilder` is not the best choice when making concatenation of two little strings but for a bunch of strings with no known size and repetition it is the best. ;)