# How do I replace words in a string that matches a keywords stored in an array with data from a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I want to replace words in a string that matches a keywords stored in an array with data from matching column in a table.

My model is People

```
public class People()
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

The method i have tried is :

```
public void ProcessString(string message)
{
 using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
            {
                var people = db.People.ToList();

                foreach(var person in people)
                {
                    string[] keyword = {"#Title", "#Name", "#Surname"};

                        for (int i=0; i<keyword.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string updatedString  = Regex.Replace(body, keyword[i], matchingcolumndata);

                    }

                }
}
```

So instead of matchingcolumndata in the  `string updatedString  = Regex.Replace(body, keyword[i], matchingcolumndata);` line i want to put the data that is matching the column in my table **People**. Please help with the question if its not straight to the point.

Comment: So you want to replace all of your string "columns"?

Comment: You need to replace the keywords by what exactly ?

Comment: I want to replace the words in a string that matches the keywords stored in  the array by column's data. For example if there's **#Title** word in a string then replace it with **people.Title** data from the People table

Comment: Check this one: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226691/replace-multiple-words-in-a-string-from-a-list-of-words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226691/replace-multiple-words-in-a-string-from-a-list-of-words) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220913/fastest-way-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-huge-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220913/fastest-way-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-huge-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understand it may be you are looking for

```
foreach(var person in people)
            {
                string[] keyword = {"#Title", "#Name", "#Surname"};
                body= body.Replace(keyword[0],person.Title);
                body= body.Replace(keyword[1],person.Name);
                body= body.Replace(keyword[2],person.Surname);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense to declare your `keywords` array inside the loop. If you want to do this in a **neat way** (and subject to modifications easily), you can create a map between the `keyword` and the property of the `Person`. Like this:

```
using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
{
    var people = db.People.ToList();

    // maps each keyword to a property in the Person class
    var keywordPropertyMapping = new Dictionary<string, Func<Person, string>>()
    {
        { "#Title", p => p.Title },
        { "#Name", p => p.Name },
        { "#Surname", p => p.Surname }
    };

    foreach (var person in people)
    {
        foreach(var keywordFunc in keywordPropertyMapping)
        {
            body = body.Replace(keywordFunc.Key, keywordFunc.Value(people));
        }
    }
}
```

For any new keyword, you just add one simple line inside the dictioanry `keywordPropertyMapping`, and the magic works.

If you're not familiar with `Func<T, TResult>` which is one critical part of the Linq magic, then read the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Encapsulates a method that has one parameter and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the TResult parameter.
>
> You can use this delegate to represent a method that can be passed as
>   a parameter without explicitly declaring a custom delegate. The
>   encapsulated method must correspond to the method signature that is
>   defined by this delegate. This means that the encapsulated method must
>   have one parameter that is passed to it by value, and that it must
>   return a value.