# Add two Replace on the same Regex at the same time - Do two different things

Tags: c#, regex

My problem is that when I for example add a point more like it needs replacing. Then it comes up with this error:

> cannot convert from string to System.stringComparison

If I thus comment on the last replace. Then there are no problems but this only happens if I have added the extra replace on my Regex.

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"{(?s)(.*){medlem}}.*{{medlemstop}}",
       "<img src=\"https://aaaa.azureedge.net/imagesfiles/hello.png\" class=\"img-responsive\" alt=\"hello world\">")
       .Replace(text, @"{(?s)(.*){pay}}.*{{paystop}}", "ERROR HERE!!!");
```

I have also tried to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276014/12596984

Comment: `Regex.Replace()` returns a string. You can't do `Regex.Replace().Replace()` and use Regex

Comment: `text = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(source, pattern, value), anotherPattern, anotherValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if only `Regex.Replace` returns `Regex` we'll be able to *chain* `Replace`: `Replace(...).Replace(...).Replace(...)`; 
but alas! the `Replace` returns `string` so we can't use `Regex` methods on it (`string`). The options are:

*Nested* calls:

```
text = Regex.Replace(
         Regex.Replace(
                 text, 
               @"{(?s)(.*){medlem}}.*{{medlemstop}}",
                "<img src=\"https://aaaa.azureedge.net/imagesfiles/hello.png\" class=\"img-responsive\" alt=\"hello world\">"),
         @"{(?s)(.*){pay}}.*{{paystop}}", 
          "ERROR HERE!!!");
```

*Sequential* calls:

```
 text = Regex.Replace(
              text, 
            @"{(?s)(.*){medlem}}.*{{medlemstop}}",
             "<img src=\"https://aaaa.azureedge.net/imagesfiles/hello.png\" class=\"img-responsive\" alt=\"hello world\">");

 text = Regex.Replace(
             text, 
            @"{(?s)(.*){pay}}.*{{paystop}}", 
             "ERROR HERE!!!");
```

Comment: Thanks for u Answer! i will try to make this simple for mig :) Good day to u!