# How do I replace a string with case insensitive search?

Tags: vb.net

In VB6, I could say:

```
s = Replace(s, "Find", "Replace", vbTextCompare)
```

In VB.NET, there is only String.Replace(uFind, uReplace) which would mean binary compare, I guess.

Is there no .NET version that would provide the usual CultureInvariantIgnoreDayTimeAndHowEmptyMyStomachIs and similar search option?

[image]

Comment: See the method [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0#overloads)!

Comment: I don't have them. I have added 2 screenshots.

Comment: Right, not under NET Framework 4x. In this case, either use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace` method to do so, or you still can use the vb6 `Replace` method. Add reference to **Microsoft.VisualBasic** (if not already) and import the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275980/string-replace-ignoring-case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String.Replace ignoring case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275980/string-replace-ignoring-case)