# how to replace a string ignoring case?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an alternative to string.Replace that is case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive)

I'm looking for alternative to:

```
string str = "data ... ";
string replace = "data";
str = str.Replace(replace, "new value");
str = str.Replace(replace.ToLower(),"new value");
```

if possible using no regex.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ignoring case in which culture? Current, or invariant?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Regex, I don't know.

With Regex, it would give you something like this :

```
var regex = new Regex( str, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
var newSentence = regex.Replace( sentence, "new value" );
```

I found an interesting article here, with a sample code that looks to work faster than Regex.Replace : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/fastestcscaseinsstringrep.aspx