# String.Replace is not working as expected

Tags: c#, string

I have a program

```
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        string[] keywords =
        {
            "SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "GROUP", "HAVING", "ORDER", "LEFT",  "RIGHT", "JOIN", "INNER", "OUTER", "ASC",
            "DESC", "AND", "OR","IN", "BETWEEN", "BY", "NOT", "ON", "AS", "CASE", "WHEN", "ELSE", "UPDATE", "SET"
        };

        var actualString = "SELECT * FROm A Join B On C in D case e join t left outer join inner join right join";

        foreach (var text in actualString.Split(' '))
        {
            var isExists = keywords.Any(x => x.Equals(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (!isExists)
            {
                continue;
            }

            actualString = actualString.Replace(text, text.ToUpper());
        }


        var expectedString = "SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e JOIN t LEFT OUTER JOIN INNER JOIN RIGHT JOIN";

    }
```

I am a newbie in C#. I am not clear why the **Replace()** method is not working as expected. It is showing the output
**SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t LEFT OUTER joIN INner joIN RIGHT joIN**

Can someone please enlighten me why Replace() is behaving like this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is behaving as expected. Here is the output line by line:

```
[SELECT] -> SELECT * FROm A Join B On C in D case e join t left outer join inner join right join
[FROm]   -> SELECT * FROM A Join B On C in D case e join t left outer join inner join right join
[Join]   -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B On C in D case e join t left outer join inner join right join
[On]     -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C in D case e join t left outer join inner join right join
[in]     -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D case e joIN t left outer joIN INner joIN right joIN
[case]   -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t left outer joIN INner joIN right joIN
[join]   -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t left outer joIN INner joIN right joIN
[left]   -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t LEFT outer joIN INner joIN right joIN
[outer]  -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t LEFT OUTER joIN INner joIN right joIN
[join]   -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t LEFT OUTER joIN INner joIN right joIN
[inner]  -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t LEFT OUTER joIN INner joIN right joIN
[join]   -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t LEFT OUTER joIN INner joIN right joIN
[right]  -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t LEFT OUTER joIN INner joIN RIGHT joIN
[join]   -> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e joIN t LEFT OUTER joIN INner joIN RIGHT joIN
```

You can see that when *in* gets replaced by *IN*, at line 5; then *join* gets replaced by *joIN*

But then, what happen is that your call to *Keywords.Any* works properly, and matches *join* and *joIN*, however, the *replace* call is still case sensitive and the replace will not take place.

Replace is C# is case sensitive and, unfortunately, .NET doesn't offer a case insensitive version; but there are solutions floating around.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244531/is-there-an-alternative-to-string-replace-that-is-case-insensitive#comment5549925_244933) for an implementation of a case insensitive replace.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Got it.

Answer (score 8):

If you debug it you will notice that your keyword "in" replaces second join so you get joIN. Later your text variable will try to replace "join" with "JOIN" but it won't find "join" because part of it was uppercased.

Comment: Since this is about an sql string and those don't start or end with an 'in' or other sql word fraction, a simple fix is to surround both needle and haystack with spaces. Also: Do note the first three words of the answer!

Comment: @Zbigniew - Actually my mistake was I thought foreach works like for loop. Now I got it. thanks.

Comment: @NoorAShuvo I can't see how it would help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you already replace the IN in join. Therefore the comparison fails when you want to replace join with JOIN. (joIN != join)

Answer (score 0):

Got a clear idea from the answers here.Finally solve that by changing the **foreach** with **for** loop. Thank you all.

```
public void TestMethod2()
{
    string[] keywords =
    {
        "SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "GROUP", "HAVING", "ORDER", "LEFT",  "RIGHT", "JOIN", "INNER", "OUTER", "ASC",
        "DESC", "AND", "OR","IN", "BETWEEN", "BY", "NOT", "ON", "AS", "CASE", "WHEN", "ELSE", "UPDATE", "SET"
    };

    var actualString = "SELECT * FROm A Join B On C in D case e join t left outer join inner join right join";

    var cnt = sqlTest.Split(' ').Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        var text = sqlTest.Split(' ')[i];
        var isExists = keywords.Any(x => x.Equals(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        if (!isExists)
        {
            continue;
        }

        actualString = actualString.Replace(text, text.ToUpper());
    }


    var expectedString = "SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON C IN D CASE e JOIN t LEFT OUTER JOIN INNER JOIN RIGHT JOIN";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Regex.Replace` instead of just `String.Replace` with

```
 \bKeyWord\b
```

*pattern* in order treating a substring as a keyword if and only if it is a *whole word*:

```
 select horror 
   from torro 
  where corner = 1 
     or ordain = 2
```

should be turned into

```
 SELECT horror -- even if horror has two "or"
   FROM torro  -- even if torro has two "or"
  WHERE corner = 1 -- even if corner contains "or"
     OR ordain = 2 -- even if ordain contains "or"
```

Implementation:

```
string[] keywords = {
  "SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "GROUP", "HAVING", "ORDER", "LEFT",  "RIGHT",
  "JOIN", "INNER", "OUTER", "ASC", "DESC", "AND", "OR","IN", "BETWEEN", 
  "BY", "NOT", "ON", "AS", "CASE", "WHEN", "ELSE", "UPDATE", "SET"
};

var actualString = 
  "SELECT * FROm A Join B On C in D case e join t left outer join inner join right join";

foreach (var keyword in keywords)
  actualString = Regex.Replace(
    actualString,
    @"\b" + Regex.Escape(keyword) + @"\b",
    keyword.ToUpper(),
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```